# vba codes to copy large data

Tags: excel, vba, copy, export

am using the following code to cope certain cells from one workbook to another but the problem is i have to repeat this code with diff data coz i have too many workbooks and when i tried to copy them i get an error msg like out of memory or procedure is too large
is there a way to make this easier and faster to copy those data from the main workbook to all the workbooks and a file

the code is :

```
Sub copy_paste1()
Dim wkb1 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim wkb2 As Workbook
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Set wkb1 = Workbooks("info.xlsm") 



Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\work\old server\Cards Tests\New folder\data\1-xxxxxxx.xlsm") 
Set sht1 = Workbooks("info.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2") 

Set sht2 = Workbooks("1-xxxxxxx.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
sht1.Range("a2").copy
sht2.Range("m4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
wkb2.Close True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\work\old server\Cards Tests\New folder\data\1043-xxxxxxx.xlsm") 
Set sht1 = Workbooks("info.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2") 

Set sht2 = Workbooks("1043-xxxxxxx.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
sht1.Range("a52").copy
sht2.Range("m4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
wkb2.Close True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\work\old server\Cards Tests\New folder\data\1044-xxxxxxx.xlsm") 
Set sht1 = Workbooks("info.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2") 

Set sht2 = Workbooks("1044-xxxxxxx.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
sht1.Range("a53").copy
sht2.Range("m4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValue, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
wkb2.Close True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
end sub
```

Comment: I don't see why you should get an out of memory error. However, as you want to copy only data (no formatting), there is no need to use Copy&Paste. Instead, use `sht2.Range("m4").Value = sht1.Range("a52").Value`.

Comment: this is not the whole code it's just a part of it and i have like 4000 workbook so it gives out of memory

Comment: Is there a relation between the row (you're going from "a2" to "a52" to "a53") and the workbooks (you're going from "1-xxx.." to "1043..." to "1044..")? Or just whichever workbook comes next gets the next row's value?

Comment: there's a relation with the workbook name

Comment: if there's away to make a code to read directly from a sheet with workbooks name in it and the data that wanted to be updated and to update it like vlookup

Answer (score 1):

We have similar situation handling large amount of datasets (i.e. csv, accdb, cross-platforms etc) as well, to improve efficiency I'd definitely limit *open, close, save* operations, avoid *unnecessary* calculations (I mostly *shut down* calc), I did consider error handling to avoid runtime error but downside is hard to check during the process while handling bulks. As you mentioned being part of your codes, some of structure below might help.

```vb
`// 2023.12.12 - refined targeting section.
`//
Sub copy_paste1()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim wkb2 As Workbook
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    
    Set wkb1 = Workbooks("info.xlsm")
    Set sht1 = wkb1.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim targetFile As String
    Dim targetFiles As Variant
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    targetFiles = sht1.Range("A1:A4000").Value
    filePath = "D:\work\old server\Cards Tests\New folder\data\"
    
    For i = LBound(targetFiles, 1) To UBound(targetFiles, 1)
        targetFile = targetFiles(i, 1)
        If targetFile <> "" Then
            Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(filePath & targetFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set sht2 = wkb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            
            CopyPasteData sht1, sht2
            
            wkb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Sub CopyPasteData(srcSht As Worksheet, dstSht As Worksheet)
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Dim dstRng As Range
    
    Set srcRng = srcSht.Range("A2")
    Set dstRng = dstSht.Range("M4")
    
    dstRng.Value2 = srcRng.Value2

End Sub
```

Comment: Do I have to change the range manually Li ke a2 and m4 or how it's gonna act

Comment: @MohamedNabil yeah you can modify as per your specifics, A2 / M4 were the range you suggested at original

Comment: It does change with every new workbook, like a2 and m4 waz for the first one and a3 for the second one and so

Comment: @MohamedNabil basically _A2_ is your source range, _M4_ is the destination range where the data will be pasted.

Comment: Exactly, a2 is the source m4 is the deztination

Comment: it returns type mismatch

Comment: @MohamedNabil it could be the mismatch error by targetfile variant at your end, just amended see it helps.

Comment: i did as an integer and it gave me an compile error, sayin for each may only iterate over a collection object or an array .

Comment: am srry when itried the new code now it saying he can't find the file.exe i didn't chang anything

Comment: @MohamedNabil umm, where does it stop? oh well that's a pain though thought we're getting there... the error identify the code was working but cannot locate a file doesn't exist at the specific path. though was trying to help anyway...

Comment: thx alot mate u did ,its stopping here Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(filePath & targetFile, ReadOnly:=True)

Comment: @MohamedNabil no worries mate... btw if you've verified the file paths are correct then could be file access permissions, or _sth else_ even (I knw I knowww...) could be causing the issue. thought you wanna a coffee break from it now then

Comment: i got it to work by changing this array ("A1:A4000") but after its finished i found it didn't copy paste anything

Comment: @MohamedNabil well that's positive, well hard to visualise as the code might be linked up with sth else. but yeah you need to play around with it with your files and datasets.

Comment: i changed ("A1:A4000") to ("BC1:BC4000") as its the column that contains the the target files name, but after it's finish running the code nthn happens i mean it didn't copy paste where do u think the problem is .

Comment: @MohamedNabil if you change  to "BC1:BC4000" for the targetFiles in the sht1 worksheet, you then also need to adjust the range for srcRng in the CopyPasteData subroutine accordingly.

Comment: i got it to work but it only pasting the value of a2 only i need it to be updated with every workbook i mean like in my code every workbook = certain value

Comment: yeah but that's from the orig structure. anyway the Q is growing snowball maybe better to work with someone on site, might be quicker

Comment: You probably should pass the iteration you're on to the CopyPasteData sub so you can offset the `srcSht.Range("A2")` if I understood it correctly, OP wants to give the current row's value to the newly opened workbook. (I'm yet to see a relation in his other statement *"there's a relation with the workbook name"*)